# How to validate a UPI ID using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

It's like an email ID but can start from a digit also and doesn't have a domain at the end.

Examples:

```
rishi.21@axis
shruti@PNB
98765__210@upi
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/XFmIrD/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that only word characters can appears either before or after the `@` symbol, we can try using the following pattern:

```
^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+$
```

```js
var result = /^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+$/.test('rishi21@axis');
console.log(result);
var result = /^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+$/.test('shruti@PNB');
console.log(result);
var result = /^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+$/.test('98765__210@upi');
console.log(result);
var result = /^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+$/.test('#stuff@other$');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: sir in above answer a@a is also right but after reading upi documentation I get to know that at least email/phone@bankname/provider is require and both should be at least 3 char before @3 char after is must

Comment: UPI id can also contain dot(.) and above regex will not match with upi id with dot

Comment: UPI ID also contains `-` hyphen

Answer (score 6):

Ideally there is a minimum number of characters before and after @. Hence following can be added for same:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{2,256}@[a-zA-Z]{2,64}
```

Comment: For those of you using javascript, don't forget to double escape the hyphen,
"[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_]{2,256}@[a-zA-Z]{2,64}"

Comment: Why do we need that? @brunoob

Answer (score 5):

This might help.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-]{2,256}\\@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]{2,64}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways of creating your UPI (Unified Payment Interface) Id, i.e. VPA (Virtual Payment Address)
1-Using phone number (use PayTm, Phone Pay, etc)
2-Using email id (use Google Pay)
So to verify valid UPI VPA we need to use regex email/phone number@bankname/paymentgateway

```
^[\w\.\-_]{3,}@[a-zA-Z]{3,}
```

Answer (score 2):

The excepted answer doesn't check all the conditions.

VPA or UPI id can have alphanumeric, period (.), hyphen (-), underscore (*) and a at sign (@). Underscore (*) and dot (.) gets accepted before and after at sign (@), but hyphen (-) get accepted only before the at sign (@)

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{2,49}@[a-zA-Z._]{2,49}
```

This expression will check for the minimum charecters, alphanumeric, period, hyphen & underscore.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{2,49}@[a-zA-Z._]{2,49}$
```

this will do a exact match.
if you want to get more understanding on this regex let me know in comments.

Comment: https://regexr.com/ try the above regex on this website.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "rishi21@axis";
var str2 = "92@in";
var match = /[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,}@[a-zA-Z]{3,}/;
console.log(match.test(str)); // True
console.log(match.test(str2)); // False
```

The regex in match will look for 3+ characters in a row that are letters, numbers or underscores, then an @ sign, then 3+ letters. Some more variations:

```
1.) /[a-zA-Z0-9_-+]{3,}@[a-zA-Z]{3,}/ 
// Searches first part for hyphens and plus signs too
2.) /[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}/
// Includes numbers in matches after the @ sign
3.) /[a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,}@[a-zA-Z]{3,}/
// Requires 5 or more matching characters before the @ sign
```

Answer (score 0):

You can support [dot] also in upi address by using below regex.

```
/^\w.+@\w+$/.test('rishi.21@axis')

/^\w.+@\w+$/.test('shruti@PNB')

/^\w.+@\w+$/.test('98765__210@upi')
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to display UPI ID's format (sxxxxxx@upi) using Regular Expression

```
const upiAddress = 'success@upi';
upiAddress.replace(/(?<=.).(?=[^@]*?@)/g, "x");
output : sxxxxxx@xyz
```